Using \ifthenelse and \isempty in newcommand used in glossaries's name
I want to use \ifthenelse while defining symbols with \newcommand. This works all fine, until I try to use those symbols (here \densCanv) in my glossary as a name:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[toc, acronym, style = long, nopostdot, order=letter, automake, automake=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossary[sylg]{sym}{syld}{sydn}{Symbols}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\notatpat}[4]{ \ifthenelse{ \isempty{#2} \AND \isempty{#3} }{ #1 }{} }
% \newcommand{\notatpat}[4]{#1}

\newcommand{\densCanv}{\ensuremath{\notatpat{b}{}{}{}}}

\newglossaryentry{sym:densCanv}{type=sym, name=\protect{\densCanv{}}, sort=ρ, description={my description}}

\glsaddall[types={sym}]

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=sym,title=Glossary of Symbols, nonumberlist]

a

\end{document}

Now I get the error "Undefined control sequence" like so (the editor Kile does not allow for copy-pasting the text):

When I comment the above \notatpat definition with \newcommand{\notatpat}[4]{#1}, then I do not get an error, so I assume it is about the logical structures.
Weirdly enough, if I replace \newcommand{\densCanv}{\ensuremath{\notatpat{b}{}{}{}}} with \newcommand{\densCanv}[1][]{\ensuremath{\notatpat{b}{}{}{}}} and leave everything else as it is, then I do not get an error either. This however, seems like bad programming to me and I would like to solve the real underlying issue.
What is the underlying issue and how can I resolve it properly, e.g., in the programming of \notatpat?

Can't test now but \protect{\densCanv{}} looks fishy. You are \protecting the brace {.

@campa: Wait... what?? Wow, if that is so... maybe I misunderstood what \protect is doing. I am also super surprised that a command does not use {} as an indicator for a block of code.

@campa: Why do not need a \protect if I have an optional argument in my symbol's definition?

I never said you don't need \protect. \protect applies to the next token, so you are applying it to the brace. If you want to protect \densCanv then you should write \protect\densCanv. But as I said I can't test and I am not even sure this is related to the issue.

@campa: Ah sorry, my answer was given to misunderstanding: I did test and once I replaced \protect{\densCanv{}} with \protect\densCanv{}, everything works fine.

The thing is this: My testing showed me that I do need a \protect only if my symbol excepts an optional argument. Whether I am using a mandatory argument or not does not matter. In other words, an optional argument seems to have the same effect as a  \protect. This surprises me.

If you click on Output rather than Log and Messages, you can copy-paste the text. Or you can open the .log file as a file in Kile. Or you can compile using the Konsole part and copy-paste the terminal output.

\ifthenelse is not expandable, i.e., with \ifthenelse some things are to be done in processing-stages which take place after expansion. Things like performing scratch-assignments.You can prevent expansion of \ifthenelse altogether by saying \protetct\densCanv for preventing expansion of \densCanv.Alternatively you can say \DeclareRobustCommand{\densCanv} instead of \newcommand{\densCanv}.This is what LaTeX does under the hood when a command defined in terms of \newcommand has an optional argument.This is because the check for [ is based on \futurelet which isn't expandable.
